# How to add thumbnails for embed video in website(Squarespace)

Tags: java, html, css, video, squarespace

I have embed some video to my website using following code.

```
<div id="container">
<video loop autoplay="autoplay" />
    <source id="mp4" src="/s/test.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
</div>
```

When entering into my site the video taking few seconds to load. And the background is black, its not looking fair. No problem if internet speed is good, otherwise its display black background for few seconds.
So how to add thumbnail while loading video or adding text called"video loading".

Comment: No need thumbnail if the video loaded, otherwise the thumbnail should display until the video start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the tag id poster

```
<video controls="controls" poster="/IMG_LOCATION/IMAGENAME">
```

More info can be found http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_video_poster.asp

I found this here: [How to make a loading image when loading HTML5 video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097605/how-to-make-a-loading-image-when-loading-html5-video)

If that doesn't work see the first answer on that page - where you could show the loading image using some javascript but this solution worked for me.