# how can i show loading gif when video loading from database like youtube

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[I Want to Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UW484.png)

```
  <script>
$("video").on("click", function() {

// All but not this one - pause
$("video").not( this ).each(function() {
     this.pause();

});
// Play this one
// this.play();

// Or rather toggle play / pause
this[this.paused ? "play" : "pause"]();

});
```

```
<video id=”myVideo” src="<?php echo $_REQUEST['video']; ?>"></video>
```

anyone can please help me please above is my code.
Thanks STACKOVERFLOW

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a loading image when loading HTML5 video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097605/how-to-make-a-loading-image-when-loading-html5-video)

Answer (score 1):

Use the poster attribute and a class to add some style, and remove them on the `canplay` event.

```js
$('video').on('loadstart waiting seeking stalled', function (event) {
  $(this).addClass('loading');
});
$('video').on('canplay seeked play', function (event) {
  $(this).removeClass('loading');
});
```

```css
video.loading {
  background: black url(/images/loader.gif) center center no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<video src="/videos/movie.mp4" poster="/images/poster.jpg" controls></video>
```

Comment: but what about if video load first time and it starts but if the video does not completely load then how can I show again loading gif

Comment: For that you can use the `waiting` event. There's also the case when the user changes the current time and a new chunk needs to be loaded, for this one you can use `seeking`. Read more about media events [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events)

Comment: I'm trying to make a demo but it's very inconsistent across browsers. Do you want the old, ugly, cross-browser solution or the new, clean and not fully supported one?

Comment: you can give me demo old new its not important

Comment: I updated the question with the new events but I haven't tested. If it works you can check this as answered.

Comment: ok send the codes I will check and give you feedback your codes